# How to unittest a struct without exposing accessor

Tags: unit-testing, racket, abstract-data-type

Suppose I want to build a Vector library. It has a Vector struct:

```
(struct vector (x y z))
```

Now I want to write unit test for vector module in the test module.
for testing I need to access x y and z. But I do not want to expose `vector-{xyz}`. Is there a way to provide accessor only for the unit tests?

Comment: Make test a submodule (in the same file)? [Unsure if that's what you are after]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed I found the a way to hide things using [submodule](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/Module_Syntax.html#%28part._submodules%29)

```
 ;; vector.rkt
 (struct vector (x y z))

 (module* private-test #f
           (provide vector-x vector-y vector-z))
```

I could then require the private-test only for the test purpose.

```
 ;; test.rkt
 (require (submod "vector.rkt" private-test)
```

Comment: Note: `(module+ foo body ...)` is the same as `(module* foo #f body ...)`, and if you name your test submodule `test`, the `raco test` tool *automatically* runs it, so you could just put all your testing code in the test submodule.

Comment: @Jack Thanks for the note. But I wanted to have all my test in an other file.